# Add (predefined) atomic values to vector in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, vector, atomic

I've faced a problem while working with multithreading in C++.

I have a class (call it **class_a_example**) which is defined in header file with public & protected access modifiers. **class_a_example** depends on several variables/structures.

In 'protected' I've defined **m_accessed** member - vector consists of atomics, and when an element of class is created, it also depends on **m_accessed**, which needs to have predefined values in m_accessed. Just like this:

```
// class_a_example_header.h

class class_a_example {
protected:
    std::vector<std::atomic<uint32_t>> m_accessed;
    std::vector<uint32_t> m_vars;
    std::mutex m_mtx;
    // some other structures

public:
    // some methods
    inline class_a_example(/*params*/, size_t c_count, /*params*/) : m_vars(c_count, 0), m_accessed(c_count, std::atomic<uint32_t>(0))
    {
        /* some actions */
    }
};
```

In **class_a_example_header.cpp** in one method of **class_a_example** I need to interact with m_accessed (need to change atomic values):

```
// class_a_example_header.cpp

int32_t class_a_example::change_values(uint32_t thread_index)
{
    /* some actions */
    m_accessed[thread_index]++;
    /* some actions */
}
```

But when I compile my program, I get an error required from (particularly in **m_accessed(c_count, std::atomic(0))**):

```
inline class_a_example(/*params*/, size_t c_count, /*params*/) : m_vars(c_count, 0), m_accessed(c_count, std::atomic<uint32_t>(0))
```

Error is:

```
class_a_example.cpp:114:57:   required from here
/opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/include/c++/8/ext/new_allocator.h:136:4: error: use of deleted function ‘std::atomic<unsigned int>::atomic(const std::atomic<unsigned int>&)’
  { ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
```

After that I've rewritten **class_a_example.h** and **class_a_example.cpp**:

```
// class_a_example_header.h

class class_a_example {
protected:
    std::vector<std::atomic<uint32_t>> m_accessed;
    // ...

public:
    inline class_a_example(/*params*/, size_t c_count, /*params*/) : m_vars(c_count, 0), m_accessed()
    {
        // ...
    }
    // ...
};



// class_a_example_header.cpp

int32_t class_a_example::change_values(uint32_t thread_index)
{
    /* some actions */
    if (m_accessed.size() < m_vars.size())
        m_accessed.emplace_back(std::atomic<uint32_t>(0));

    m_accessed[thread_index]++;
    /* some actions */
}
```

But error in general is the same, only it starts from here: `m_accessed.emplace_back(std::atomic<uint32_t>(0));`

**Is there any way (preferably simple) to create predefined atomic vector or add values to it?**

Comment: it seems there is initialization problem with m_accessed variable. please check:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29332897/error-c2280-attempting-to-reference-a-deleted-function-atomicint

Comment: @Pankaj thank you, I'll try this variant

Comment: Your question lacks a [mcve]. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask]. That said, mixing a mutex with atomics is probably a bad idea. Do you have a specific reason for that?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I need to use atomics not under mutex, they are like flags, which report when mutex needs to be turn on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a SOLUTION to define atomic vector with values I want to use. It has solved the problem

```
// class_a_example_header.h

class class_a_example {
protected:
    std::vector<std::atomic<uint32_t>> m_accessed;
    // some other structures

public:
    // some methods
    inline class_a_example(/*params*/, size_t c_count, /*params*/) : m_vars(c_count, 0), m_accessed(c_count)
    {
        for (auto it = m_accessed.begin(); it != m_accessed.end(); it++)
            std::atomic_init(&*it, 0u) //instead of 0u specify value you want to be in atomic
    }
};
```

After this actions atomic vector will be created successfully & defined with values you want.

Answer (score 1):

std::atomic hasn't copy constructor.

Use

```
m_accessed.emplace_back();
m_accessed.back().store(0);
```

Instead of

```
m_accessed.emplace_back(std::atomic<uint32_t>(0));
```

Comment: I've tried your variant, but unfortunately it gets the same mistake as I got

Comment: The explanation is right though and your code makes that mistake. It's up to you to extract and create a [mcve] now, so that we get a common base for this discussion.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I've tried this code and it doesn't solve the mistake. I have found the solution myself, if you interested - you can check it below https://stackoverflow.com/a/59946282/12782346