# c++ unorderd_map insert fails for value_type with atomic<bool> member

Tags: c++, c++17, gcc9

```
class strategy
{
    int id;
    std::atomic<bool> strategyStarted;
    int startTime;
    int endTime;

    void getStartTime() { return startTime; }
    void setStartTime(int sTime) { startTime = sTime; }
};

class strategyImpl{

    std::unordered_map<int, strategy> allStrategies;

    strategyImpl()
    {
        strategy newParams;
        newParams.id = 1;
        newParams.strategyStarted.store(false);
        newParams.startTime = 104500;
        newParams.endTime = 150500;
        allStrategies.insert(std::make_pair(newParams.id, newParams)); <--ERROR
    }
};
```

The problem arises when I try to insert/insert_or_assign/emplace to the unordered map allStrategies.
Below are all the tried methods and their specific compiler errors.

```
allStrategies.insert(std::make_pair(newParams.id, newParams));
```

> error: no matching function for call to ‘std::unordered_map<int, strategy>::insert(std::pair<int, strategy>)’

```
allStrategies.insert(std::pair<int, strategy>(newParams.id, newParams));
```

> error: no matching function for call to ‘std::pair<int, strategy>::pair(int&, strategy&)’

```
allStrategies.insert(std::unordered_map<int, strategy>::value_type(newParams.id, newParams));
```

> error: no matching function for call to ‘std::pair<const int, strategy>::pair(int&, strategy&)’

```
allStrategies.insert_or_assign(newParams.id, newParams);
```

> error: use of deleted function ‘strategy& strategy::operator=(const strategy&)’

```
allStrategies.emplace(newParams.id, newParams);
```

> error: no matching function for call to ‘std::pair<const int, strategy>::pair(int&, strategy&)’

I have tried all possible ways, but just am not able to insert into this unorderd_map.
As far as I have read about these ways to add entries to a map, the value type is not required to have default constructor or copy constructor.

Please help me insert key value pairs to this map. How to do it?

**Edit:**

Added the problem causing member to class definition (it was omitted for conciseness)
The root cause seems to be the member `atomic<bool> strategyStarted`

After removal of the member, insert(make_pair..) compiles fine.

Do I really have to do it without the atomic type?

Comment: please post a [mcve].

Comment: if all of them fail, then maybe the reason is the same in all cases, then one complete example would be sufficient. As it currently stands one has to add lots of missing details to your code just to arrive at some code that does not have the issue.

Comment: `error: use of deleted function ‘strategy& strategy::operator=(const strategy&)’` indicates that you are not actually showing your real class. The class you are showing does not have its copy assignment operator deleted. The issue is with how your _real_ class looks like. It seems to be non-copyable, so that it makes sense that you can't store a copy of it in the unordered_map or a pair. Please form a proper [mre].

Comment: Did you define a hash function for your type?

Comment: kudos for trying to supply many details, but unfortunately you supplied the wrong ones. Rather than several variants of a incomplete snippet it will be better to have one complete example that others can use to reproduce one error

Comment: "_the value type is not required to have default constructor or copy constructor._": The map itself does not require a copy constructor for the value type, but you do need a copy constructor if you are trying to store a copy of a value type object in it. If you don't want to store a copy, but instead move `newParams` into the map, then write `std::move(newParams)`.

Comment: Given the code shown so far my best guess would be `allStrategies.try_emplace(newParams.id, std::move(newParams));`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number : I have edited the question to reflect necessary changes. I figured it only after posting the question.

Comment: pedantically this is still not a [mcve]. It is so much easier to write an answer when you post code that can be copy/pasted and compiled to produce the same error you see. Anyhow, now its enough information to know what is causing the problem

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number: added the minimal reproducible example

Comment: @john: try_emplace gives `error: use of deleted function ‘ud15LevelsStrategy::ud15LevelsStrategy(const ud15LevelsStrategy&)’`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15249998/why-are-stdatomic-objects-not-copyable and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961043/copy-constructor-for-classes-with-atomic-member

Comment: This is not a MCVE ... `std` is not defined, and there is a `void` function returning a value ... please check that compiling the code exactly as posted produces the error you claim it produces. You can use https://godbolt.org/ or other online compielrs to help prepare the example if it would help

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12003024/error-with-copy-constructor-assignment-operator-for-a-class-which-has-stdatomi.

Comment: I would say the cleaner design would remove `strategyStarted` from the `startegy` and introduce a new class `strategyExecution` which contains `strategyStarted` and `strategyStarted` as a member. I'm assuming the atomic is there because there's some synchronisation between threads of strategy executions. The copy assignment is deleted to avoid errors where atomics are copied around but a memory barrier for one isn't a memory barrier for another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the basic problem is that the compiler isn't able to generate the default copy constructor because of the `std::atomic`. So you must write one for yourself. E.g.

```
class strategy
{
public:
    strategy() = default;
    strategy(const strategy& rhs) 
        : id(rhs.id)
        , strategyStarted(rhs.strategyStarted.load())
        , startTime(rhs.startTime)
        , endTime(rhs.endTime)
    {
    }
    strategy& operator=(const strategy& rhs); // to do
    int id;
    std::atomic<bool> strategyStarted;
    int startTime;
    int endTime;

    int getStartTime() { return startTime; }
    void setStartTime(int sTime) { startTime = sTime; }
};
```

With that addition, all (or most) of your previous attempts should work.

On the other hand you could write a move constructor, in which case `try_emplace` and similar will work.

Whichever you choose you should also also add the corresponding assignment operator.

Comment: I'll try this when I'm done reading the posts shared by 463035818_is_not_a_number. Also, why is the assignment operator required?

Comment: @PrabalKajla In case you ever want to assign a strategy object. For example `allStrategies[id] = s;`